# Easily understand presheaf as a functor

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

In category theory, a presheaf on a category $C$ is a functor $F: C^{op}\longrightarrow Set$. If $C$ is the poset of open sets in a topological space, interpreted as a category, then one recovers the usual notion of presheaf on a topological space.

When there is a topological space $\mathscr{T}$, there is a corresponding Ring for each open set.
[image]

I know that we can think of a continuous function as an example for presheaf like above picture.
There is a continuous function defined in the open interval $(-2,2)$, and even if this function is reduced to a smaller $(-1,1)$, it becomes a continuous function. And a collection of continuous functions becomes a Ring.

We can express this relationship as follows:

> $(-2,2) \longrightarrow \mathscr{F}(-2,2)$
>
> $\downarrow$
>
> $(-1,1) \longrightarrow \mathscr{F}(-1,1)$

(In this diagram $\downarrow$ means restriction.)

However, when I think of presheaf as a continuous function like this, I wonder how I should think about it from the perspective of a category theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing you are referring to the following, I split it up into two parts.

**Topology:**

Let $X$ be a topological space, for example the space $(-2,2)\subset \mathbb{R}$ as above.
For an open subset $U\subseteq X$, one defines the set $\mathrm{Cont}(U,\mathbb{R})$ of continuous maps $f\colon U \to \mathbb{R}$.
As a general principle: The restriction of a continuous function is continuous. To an inclusion of opens $i\colon U\to V$ we may assign the function of sets
$$
i^*=\mathrm{res}\colon \mathrm{Cont}(V,\mathbb{R})\to \mathrm{Cont}(U,\mathbb{R}),
$$
which precomposes with $i$. Note also the reversal of the order of $U$ and $V$.
This assignment from inclusions to restrictions is compatible with composition.

**Category theory:**

We define a category $\mathbf{Ouv}(X)$ coming from the poset of open subsets of $X$, ordered by inclusion.
We now define a functor $\mathcal{F}\colon \mathbf{Ouv}(X)^{\mathrm{op}}\to \mathbf{Set}$ as follows:

On objects, it should send an open subset $U$ to the set $\mathcal{F}(U) = \mathrm{Cont}(U,\mathbb{R})$. Now onto morphisms: in $\mathbf{Ouv}(X)^{\mathrm{op}}$ there is a morphism $V\to U$ if and only if there is an inclusion of open sets $U\subseteq V$. In this case we assign to it the morphism
$$
\mathrm{res}\colon \mathrm{Cont}(V,\mathbb{R})\to \mathrm{Cont}(U,\mathbb{R})
$$
of sets. It is now easy to check that this is a functor, by the compatibility of the restriction maps we noticed above.

To your questions in the comments:

1. What I have described above is a *sheaf of sets*, often simply called a *sheaf*. What you seem to be referencing is a *sheaf of rings*, a functor $\mathcal{G}\colon \mathbf{Ouv}(X)^{\mathrm{op}}\to \mathbf{Ring}$.
   We may upgrade our functor $\mathcal{F}$ to such a sheaf as follows.
   Noting that the objects $\mathcal{F}(U) = \mathrm{Cont}(U,\mathbb{R})$ are already rings in the obvious way, and that the restriction maps are already maps of rings, we may define $\mathcal{F'}\colon\mathbf{Ouv}(X)^{\mathrm{op}}\to \mathbf{Ring}$ like this on objects, and the same way as $\mathcal{F}$ on morphisms.
   Now with $i\colon (-1,1)\to (-2,2)$ and
   $$ f\colon (-2,2)\to \mathbb{R}, \quad x \mapsto x^3-4x+5 $$
   we have $\mathcal{F}'(i^{\mathrm{op}})(f) = f\mid_{(-1,1)}$.
2. There was a typo which I have fixed.

Comment: Hello, first, I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Let me express my understanding from your answer with an example. Let's say there is a function $f(x)=x(x-2)(x+2)+5=x^3-4x+5 .$ And the open interval $(-2,2)=U , (-1,1)=V.$ And the set of these continuous functions forms a ring. Therefore, both $Cont(U,R)$ and $Cont(V,R)$Therefore, the restriction becomes $Cont(U,R) \to Cont(V,R)$

Comment: There are two questions here.                                   1. Is the concept of Sheaf changing from a ring to a ring in category theory?                                      2. In the paragraph above, $Cont(U,R)$ and $Cont(V,R)$ are not reversed. For what reason  can the two objects be reversed in this example?

Comment: (In the first comment....) Therefore, both $Cont(U,R)$ and $Cont(V,R)$ form ring. And set $U$ is bigger than set $V$. So the set of continuous function $Cont$'s restriction becomes $Cont(U,R) \to Cont(V,R)$.

Comment: I have edited the post to answer your questions.

Comment: I see it! I'm really thanks for your help!!